# Create image gallery from drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to create app that shows image from drawable, e.g. gallery application. I`m using this guide [link guide](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/), but I want show images from drawable resources, not from SD card. Can you give me some advice what I need change in this code, I guess I should change in Utils.class. Sorry for my English and Im newbie android dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Define the drawables in an array 
int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.thingOne,      R.drawable.thingTwo};
```

later... access them like this based on position
    myImageView.setImageResource(myimagelist[i]);